# Need help to rectify this javascript code

Tags: javascript, forms, firebase-authentication

I have written a form validation with firebase Javascript code.Now What I need to do is after successful login it should redirect to another html and If the user enters wrong password it should give an error like wrong password.

JavaScript Code:

```
let email=document.getElementById('email');
let password=document.getElementById('password');
let button=document.getElementById('submit');
let show=document.getElementById('discriber');

button.addEventListener('click',function(){
    login();
});

function login(){
   e=email.value;
   p=password.value;

   firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(e,p);
}
console.log("working");

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user)=>{

if(user){
    show.innerHTML="Logged in Successfully";
    location.href = "manager.html";
} else {
    show.innerHTML="Please login ";
}
```

Comment: It's hard to understand what issue you're running into without a [mwe](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What issue are you running into?

Comment: Please show runnable code. Where for example is email defined?

Comment: @asyncawait Code is working fine but when I am clicking on Login button if the credentails are correct then its redirecting me to other html Everything is perfect till here...I want add if the user puts wrong password then a alert box should come up with Login error

Comment: probably a classic need to prevent default action and manually redirect then? Usually an issue if it's inside a <form> element in the html.